# Persistent error message

Tags: matrix

I am trying to identify a submatrix inside a larger matrix and compare its elements to a query matrix of the same size/dimension as the submatrix.

Here is my code, and the error message:

```
(* Define M and N' *)
M = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};
Nprime = {{6, 7}, {10, 11}};

(* Use ImageCorrelate to find N in M *)
corr = ImageCorrelate[Image[M], Image[Nprime]];

(* Find the position of the maximum correlation *)
pos = Position[ImageData[corr], Max[ImageData[corr]]][[1]];

(* Extract Nex from M *)
Nex = Take[Take[M, {pos[[1]], pos[[1]] + Length[Nprime] - 1}, 
     {pos[[2]], pos[[2]] + Length[Nprime[[1]]] - 1}]]
```

> Take::take: Cannot take positions 4 through 5 in {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}}.

Comment: Image data must be between 0 and 1.

Comment: I am not sure `ImageCorrelate`/`ListCorrelate` will give what you want: Larger numbers will result in a bigger "correlation", regardless of whether the matrices actually match. Concretely: In your example, the lower right entries of `M` are largest, so the corresponding entry in `corr` will be largest (this is of course not entirely general, but the point still stands that it wont work the way you want it)

Answer (score 1):

As noted in the comments, the default correlation function will not give what you are after. Instead, I think you need to supply a custom correlation function to [`ListCorrelate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ListCorrelate.html) (which is anyway better than [`ImageCorrelate`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/ImageCorrelate.html) in your case because it directly works on lists):

```
m = {{1, 2, 3, 4}, {5, 6, 7, 8}, {9, 10, 11, 12}, {13, 14, 15, 16}};
nprime = {{6, 7}, {10, 11}};

corr = ListCorrelate[nprime, m, {1, -1}, 0, Subtract, Norm@*List]
(* {{10, 8, 6}, {2, 0, 2}, {6, 8, 10}} *)


pos = Position[corr, Min[corr]][[1]];

(*Extract n from m*)
n = m[[
   pos[[1]] ;; pos[[1]] + Length@Nprime - 1,
   pos[[2]] ;; pos[[2]] + Length[Nprime[[1]]] - 1
   ]]
(* {{6, 7}, {10, 11}} *)
```

Here, I use `Subtract` and `Norm@*List` to define the generalized norm - this will effectively compute $\sqrt{\sum_{i,j} |m_{i,j}-n'_{i,j}|^2}$, which should give a better measure of correlation for your case (of course it is not necessarily optimal if the matrices don't match exactly and you want a different weighting of the individual errors)

Comment: Looks like a good way to proceed. Thanks.